# How to see badges in Stack Overflow app

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

How can I see the badges I earned and their progress in the Stack Overflow app? I don't see an option for this in the profile page. Is there a way to view and track badges in the app just like in the site?

Answer (score 2):

You can view the badges you earn next to your inbox button in the top right corner. I don’t believe you can see the progress of the achievements without going to the actual site. But you’re able to see when you complete an achievement and earn a badge.